# What would be the best microcontroller for running PID calculations?

Tags: microcontroller, robotics, pid-controller

I need a microcontroller for my line following robot.
Which one would be the best considering a price below $30 and preferably >120MHz clock?

Comment: Specific hardware recommendations are off-topic for this site. You're also missing requirement info, such as power consumption, interfaces, etc.

Comment: It's because i don't need any non-standard interfaces and with 400W engine power draw energy consumption is a non-issue.

Comment: ... but we don't know that, until you tell us.

Comment: Is there anything else I forgot to include?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run PID on just about anything, it's mainly a question of how quickly you need to update.  However, 120 MHz is overkill for a line following robot, unless it has to be doing a ton of other processing.